# Strange connection time-out using winsock

Tags: c++, winapi, timeout, winsock

I've been stuck debugging my custom downloader all morning now and I finally know where it goes wrong but I don't know why.

Let me explain: I'm coding a HTTP downloader just using the basic winsock functions, not using any fancy class or framework. I don't mind if it blocks because it is already running in a separate thread so actually I just use the example code on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737591(v=VS.85).aspx

Sending the request:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n
Host: www.example.com\r\n
User-Agent: MyCustomDownloader/1.0\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

And in the receive loop I do some allocation, parse header lines, open file handle, etc. So it does not receive all in one go, it takes some time. But I suppose that shouldn't be a problem right? I receive in blocks of 4096 bytes.

All is fine but sometimes recv returns -1 before it returns 0. And when I call WSAGetLastError() it returns 10060 indicating:

```
WSAETIMEDOUT

Connection timed out.
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed 
because the connected host has failed to respond.
```

First I thought it was the host, but I observe the behavior with any host...

Is this normal for HTTP connections that they just drop-out from time to time? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might want to post your modifications to the sample code.

Comment: A connected socket blocking in **recv** should never return WSAETIMEDOUT, it just waits forever if there are no data (unless you configure some fancy timeouts yourself). So I'd dare say that you are doing something wrong, but we'll need to see some code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, good to hear recv shouldn't return WSAETIMEDOUT. I didn't set any sock options so time-outs are the defaults (which are pretty long). And yes I should post some code, but it's all scattered in my own classes right now. I think I should break down my code piece by piece sometime this week, but I hate doing that..

Comment: Actually, IIRC, the default timeout for *recv()* is infinite, pretty long indeed.

Comment: I am facing a simmilar problem. I see recv() failing with WSAETIMEDOUT after I shutdown() the sending side of the socket. This is required in HTTP/1.0, when no Content-Length header is used. 120s later, recv() returns WSAETIMEDOUT.

shutdown() seems to activate a 120s RX timeout on the socket. It does not fail, if there still is data recieved, but if there is a 120s gap in the RX data stream, recv() failes on a half-open sockets on **windows**.

Comment: I found the SO_RCVTIMEO socket option and setting this option to a value less than 120000 decreases the unwanted recv() timeout, but values greather than 120000 do not extend the timeout period. :-( There seems to be two independent receive timers.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you arr not getting 10060 from recv. You are getting it from the connect function and the problem may be at specifying the host address.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look, indeed I only called the `WSAGetLastError` after the erroneous `recv`... The way I solved it for now is just closing the connection and sending the HTTP request again, up to 3 retries. Some servers just don't respond like expected, you think the connection should be lost as well if you fail to receive data. But maybe some packets get lost in the mist and the close connection packet as well, at least that's my guess.